# How to stretch list items' to 100% when one item overflows?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to stretch the list items' width (or at least the one with the gray background)
so when the container is scrolled, the background will be displayed all the way to the right end.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul style="width: 100px; overflow:auto auto; border: 1px solid black">
    <li style="background-color: gray;">hello</li>
    <li>verylongitem!!!!!!!!!!</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just use `ul{display: grid;}`

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code.

it should to know this problem happening when you text don't have any space character.

but you can follow below code

```css
li {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

or inline style

```html
<ul style="width: 100px; overflow:auto auto; border: 1px solid black">
    <li style="background-color: gray;">hello</li>
    <li style="word-break: break-all;">verylongitem!!!!!!!!!!</li>
  </ul>
```

also you can set a space between your `li` text content like this text `verylongitem!!!!!!!!!!` convert to `verylongitem!! !!!!!!!!`